# Change plotly choropeth font and legend size

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have the following code to generate a county level map of vote change between 2016 and 2020.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)


import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='vote_change',
                           color_continuous_scale="magma",
                           range_color=(-25, 35),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=2, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.75,
                           title='Figure 2: Change in Turnout from 2016 to 2020',
                           labels={'total_votes_2016':'TEST'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":40,"l":0,"b":0})
)

fig.show()

fig.write_image("../figures/vote_change_map.png", width = 450, height = 250)
```

The code renders this resulting png.

[image]

I would like to make the title text size 8 and potentially make the legend more narrow so that it does not take up as much space. Does anyone know the way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let's start with changing `title font size = 8`. Then we will solve the issue related to `legend size`. For changing `font-size = 8` Kindly refer to the Updated Code stated below:-

```
# Import all the Libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen
import plotly.express as px
import json

# Open JSON File Using 'urlopen' Module of 'json' library and used 'json.load()' JSON Loader to load JSON Data
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

# Used Mapbox choropleth map, each row of 'data_frame (df)' is represented by a colored region on a Mapbox map.
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='vote_change',
                           color_continuous_scale="magma",
                           range_color=(-25, 35),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=2, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.75,
                           labels={'total_votes_2016':'TEST'}
                          )
                          
# Updated Layout for 'Title with Font Size 8' and 'Narrower Legend'
fig.update_layout(
    title='Figure 2: Change in Turnout from 2016 to 2020',
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=40, b=0),
    font=dict(size=8),
)

# Show Plotted Figure
fig.show()

# Store Image of Generated Plot 
fig.write_image("../figures/vote_change_map.png", width = 450, height = 250)
```

I have used the same code provided by you. Now, We can move towards `legends size`.

So, According to me, you can't change `legend size`. You got `bigger legend size` due to defined Image Size. Current Image Size is squashing all layout.

There are 2 Solution which may help you:-

**NOTE:-** All the parameters related to `position` and `size` are expected. You can fill it up according to your requirements.

**(1.) Plot Legend in `horizontal` Format:-**

If you don't want to Change Image Size. Then you can try to plot `legend` in `horizontal` format. For doing this task reference code was given below:-

```
fig.update_layout( 
    # customize legend orientation & position
    legend=dict(
        title=None, orientation = 'h', y=1, yanchor="bottom", x=0.5, xanchor="center"
    )
)
```

**NOTE:-** If you want to learn more about `orientation`, `x`, `xanchor` or more operation  related to `plotly legends` then you can refer: [Official Plotly Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/choropleth/)

**(2.) Change Image Size:-**

If you want to change `Image Size` then you can refer code given below:-

```
# Added 'width=600' and 'height=400' in Current Code for Ploting Chroleopath Mapbox
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='vote_change',
                           width=600, height=400,
                           color_continuous_scale="magma",
                           range_color=(-25, 35),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=2, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.75,
                           labels={'total_votes_2016':'TEST'}
                          )
```

and if it looks perfect then you can store it using the same `size` Using:-

```
# Store Image of Generated PLot 
fig.write_image("../figures/vote_change_map.png", width = 600, height = 400)
```

Hope this Solution will be helpful to you.